# Firebase SDK v3 for nodejs does not support `signInWithCustomToken(token)`

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

The Firebase SDK v3 for node JS does not support authenticating with custom generated tokens the same way the web SDK does, the method is simply not there.

How should NodeJS applications running on client machines that wish to have limited visibility over nodes in the realtime database authenticate with this new approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This scenario is supported since [release 3.3 of the Firebase JavaScript SDK](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#3.3.0).

> Client Authentication APIs are now available in Node.js. When you call intializeApp(), pass a serviceAccount to use the Authentication for Servers APIs in your app, or pass an apiKey to use the client Authentication APIs

Versions 3.0-3.2.1 of the Firebase SDK for Node.JS require that you have access to a service account/private key for the Firebase project. For that reason they are only targeted for use in a server-side environment.

Comment: Thanks Frank. So the only workaround would be to generate tokens with the old structure for such apps (and using old Firebase SDK), support both kinds of tokens in our backends and hope that the upcoming release is out before the old SDK is totally deprecated ? :-)

Comment: I too, face this barrier and hope for a speedy resolution.